# Cluster 1D data with noise tolerance

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, k-nearest-neighbour, hierarchical-clustering

Let's say I have a 1D list :

```
[0,0, 1,1,1, -1,-1,-1,-1, 1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,1,-1]
```

I wish to separate them into groups of -1 and 1, with certain tolerance for noise. Group boundary can be 0 (flat) or opposite sign. The objective is to identify chains of -1 and 1, with certain tolerance and best-guess where the chain stops.

An example of outcome

```
[0,0] (flat, no interesting events)
[1,1,1] (chain of 1)
[-1,-1,-1,-1, 1,1,-1,-1] (tolerance of two 1's within chain of -1)
[1,1,1,0,1,1] [0] or [1,1,1,0,1,1,0] (tolerance of some flat 0's within chain of 1
[-1,-1,1,-1] (tolerance of a noise 1 in the chain of -1)
```

My attempt is to use cumulative sum :
For `[-1,-1,-1,-1, 1,1,-1,-1]` the cumulative sum is `[-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-3,-4]` . The sum is still negative -> still in chain of -1

This seems weak as it means the opposite chain has to go for a while before being identified

Example : `[-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1]` with cumulative sum `[-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1,0]` and therefore the chain is still -1, which is not very intuitive.

Hence I'm thinking of something more elaborated such  as clustering.

Any thoughts ?

---

An extended problem : Each group bears a value and this value impacts tolerance.

```
[(red, 50), (red, 48), (green, 54)...] -> tolerated and conclude 'this is still red group'
[(red, 50), (red, 48), (green, 62)...] -> too different and conclude 'red group stops. Start considering as if green group starts'
```

How will the solution change ?

Comment: [tag:hidden-markov-model]?

Comment: Thanks. I'll start with that, but do you happen to have any more detailed examples for this use-case ?